# Is the order of a number $\mathrm{mod}N$ always smaller than $N$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is probably very obvious, but I can't convince myself of it. Given $x<N$ coprime integers, is it always true that the smallest integer $r$ such that $x^r-1=0\,\mathrm{mod}N$ is such that $r<N$?

Comment: $x^r$ must be congruent to a number in $\{1,\ldots,N-1\}$, so $x$ generates a group of order $\le N-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The least (positive) such integer is in fact smaller or equal than $$\varphi(N)=\#\{y\in\{0,\cdots, N-1\}\,:\,\operatorname{gcd}(y,N)=1\}\le N-1$$

by [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem).